# Using Protocols in django models raises metaclass conflict error

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, protocols, pep

Let's say I have [PEP-544](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/) protocol called Summable :

```py
class Summable(Protocol):
    @property
    total_amount()-> Decimal:
      ...
```

And I have model `Item` that implements the `Protocol`

```py
class Item(Summable, models.Model):
    discount = models.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=2,
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(1)],
        default=Decimal('0.00'),
        max_digits=10
    )
    price = models.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=4,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0)],
        max_digits=10
    )

    @property
    def total_amount(self) - > Decimal:
       return self.price - self.price * self.discount

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']
```

I get:

```
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

The same happens even if I extend Item's Meta from Summable.Meta and models.Model.Meta as well.

I am using python `3.9`
Any ideas?

Comment: Heads up that ``Item`` does not implement the ``Summable`` protocol! ``total_amount: Decimal`` implies a readable *and writeable* attribute. A plain ``@property`` is only readable.

Comment: Very interesting point

Comment: @MisterMiyagi so what you are suggesting for read-only fields in protocols is my current correction? ie declaring it with `@property`

Comment: Thanks for spotting just playing around with typed python, all this is fascinating xD

Comment: If anybody wants to play with the read-only property case, here is a gist:
https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=351ccc44d01fb62905773291076f0ec0

Comment: The simplest fix is to define ``total_amount`` as a ``@property`` in the protocol as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,  there are many gotchas out there:

1. You need to create a new metaclass:

For Example:

```
class ModelProtocolMeta(type(Model), type(Protocol)):
     pass
```

2. You need to place the protocol last in order  so that  protocol doesn't overwrite the model's constructor with no_init.
   Protocol's no_init constructor is as follows:

```
def _no_init(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if type(self)._is_protocol:
        raise TypeError('Protocols cannot be instantiated')
```

so it would just overwite constuctor  silently without any error since inherited class will have `_is_protocol` set to `False`

(note that super is not called, so we are talking about a complete overwrite)

so at the end of the day we need the following:

```
class Item(models.Model, Summable, metaclass=ModelProtocolMeta):
    discount = models.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=2,
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(1)],
        default=Decimal('0.00'),
        max_digits=10
    )
    price = models.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=4,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0)],
        max_digits=10
    )

    @property
    def total_amount(self) -> Decimal:
       return sel.price - self.price * self.discount
```

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to what Andreas did but I think a bit easier to use:

```py
from typing import Protocol
from django.db import models
from typing import Any

django_model_type: Any = type(models.Model)
protocol_type: Any = type(Protocol)

class ModelProtocolMeta(django_model_type, protocol_type):
    """
    This technique allows us to use Protocol with Django models without metaclass conflict
    """
    pass

class Summable(Protocol):
    def total_amount(self) -> int: ...

class SummableModel(Summable, metaclass=ModelProtocolMeta): ...
```

And use it:

```py
class Money(models.Model, SummableModel):
    def total_amount(self) -> int:
        return 100_000_000
```

Comment: This is brilliant! It allows to solve the metaclass conflict without having to change the metaclass on every "leaf" class, but just the mixins. By the way, this works with Pydantic models too.